Why Gerrit Only Shows the Latest Change Instead of the Full File Update when pushed from one branch to other

Branch Setup:
• I started with a main branch.
• Then, I created a task branch from main.
Incremental Changes:
• On task, I edited my.txt multiple times:
• First, I added “Shape” and committed and pushed it.
• Then, I added “Roshan” in the same file, committed, and pushed again.
• Finally, I added “Anand,” committed, and pushed once more.
• Each of these changes was merged back into task after being pushed.
3.Final Pull Request to main:
After all these changes, I opened a pull request from task to main.
But, in the Gerrit review window, it only shows the change in my.txt as if it’s going from Roshan to Anand, instead of displaying the whole set of changes from an empty file to Shape, Roshan, Anand.

what should i do so that i dont loose change history of the file?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How did you make a "pull request" in gerrit?  What commands did you run? If you have multiple commits on a task branch, be sure not to squash during your merge.

I think your ideas on how Gerrit works are quite confused, maybe my medium blog can help: https://medium.com/@danielesassoli/improve-your-code-review-with-gerrit-82a51dfc64d1
